# Build a mex file under matlab

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a problem to creat a mex file under matlab. It's display this:

> > cd C:\Users\Assil\Desktop
> >     mex Untitled.c

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'Untitled.c' not found.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Anny ideas what is the problem. I set up correctly the compiler as below:

mex -setup

Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/win32.html

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files:

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013a\sys\lcc

[0] None

Compiler: 1

Please verify your choices:

Compiler: Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 
Location: C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013a\sys\lcc

Are these correct [y]/n? y

Trying to update options file: C:\Users\Assil\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013a\mexopts.bat 
From template:              C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\win32\mexopts\lccopts.bat

Done . . .

Comment: What's the output of `ls`? The error message clearly suggests that Untitled.c cannot be found...

Comment: Why don't you use visual studio compiler under windows? you can install the "express" edition.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

void hello()
{

printf("\nHello world\n");

}


int main()
{
    hello();
}

Comment: Your c-code doesn't matter at all, when mex is unable to find your c-code file. Besides - this c code will not work as a mex-function. You'll have to implement a function called `mexFunction` instead of the classical `main`. You should definitely check the documentation first...

Comment: Have a look to this [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html) and this [to compile it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please set matlab directory to your file location.
like this image :
this address should be set to cpp file location.

[image]